# FooterTemplate in GridView horizontal orientation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I develop Win8.1 universal app.

I'm using GridView with WrapGrid as ItemsPanel inside. Verticall scrolling is disabled, user needs to scroll horizontally only. I'm using incremental source collection as ItemsSource and when user scrolls right to the end of the GridView, new items are dynamically added. Everything works fine, except one thing. I want to make a progress indicator right-aligned and it must become visible when new page is loading. I try to set footer template for grid view, but it is hidden (bc maybe by default footer is added below the itemspanel or whatever).

Here is the code i use to define control template for GridView and put Footer right.

```
<GridView.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" 
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                          BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" 
                                          HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" 
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                          IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" 
                                          IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" 
                                          IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" 
                                          IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" 
                                          IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" 
                                          TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" 
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                          VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" 
                                          ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ItemsPresenter HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                    Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                    HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}"
                                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                    <ContentControl Transitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}" 
                                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Footer}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </GridView.Template>
```

Then i set ProgressRing as footer template.

```
<GridView.FooterTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressRing VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      IsActive="{Binding IsBusy}"
                                      Margin="0,24"
                                      Width="50"
                                      Height="50"
                                      Foreground="{StaticResource LightGreyBorderBrush}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingStyle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.FooterTemplate>
```

But when i try to scroll - the things are going crazy. GridView always calls next page loading one after another, but the scroll position is nearly 0 (in the beginning of the GridView). So i get the infinite page loading.

Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I've created a small sample to reproduce. Please take a look. Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7fi0tqwgcy7q8k/Horizontall%20scrolling%20issue.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right aligned `FooterTemplate` is supported out of the box. Just use `ItemsWrapGrid` (it's used in `GridView` by default) instead of `WrapGrid` as `ItemsPanel`. You also don't need to redefine `Template`. Here is working code from your example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="TestGridView">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid ItemHeight="100"
                          Orientation="Vertical"
                          MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="DarkSlateGray"
                        Height="100"
                        Width="100"
                        Margin="20">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                               Text="{Binding Number}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.FooterTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ProgressRing IsActive="True"
                              Margin="0,24"
                              Width="50"
                              Height="50" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.FooterTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Please note that 2 pages are loaded each time you scroll to the right as `GridView` thinks one page is not enough.

Hope this helps.